# Android Preferences : issue while using an edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, preferences

I'm new to android,I have an edit text and I wanted to save the text entered on it through preferences.Can any one help me out....

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
 et.setText(settings.getString("tvalue"," "));
```

Then override onstop() method

@Override

```
protected void onStop() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
    editor.putString("tvalue", et.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 3 ways to persist data in android:

1. Shared Preferences
2. Local Files (xml, csv, etc)
3. Sql Lite Database

Here is some code to get you started with "Shared Preferences"

```
//get reference to a Shared Preferences instance
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Some Name You Make Up", 0);

//add a string to the given Shared Preferences store by key
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("some_key", "some_value");

//read the value from the Shared preferences
String value = preferences.getString("some_key", " ");
```

Here is the link to the android documentation on shared preferences.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Enjoy!